# How to fetch currently executing test case details from azure using NUnit test methods

Tags: testing, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, nunit-3.0

I am using azure release pipelines to trigger selected automated test cases which are associated to a NUnit test method.
Each of these azure test cases has parameters, which I am trying to fetch as part of the test execution.
For this to happen, I need the currently executing test case information, so that I can query the test case parameters from azure and use them in test execution.

I only found "**TCMTestPropertiesJSONFile**" from test context parameters, which consists of test case information and other details.

What I am trying to achieve:

once the test execution is started, I need the currently executing test case details (be it test case id\test case title etc..) for me to query azure to get test case parameters and use them in execution. and repeat the same process for remaining tests. currently there are 5000 test cases approximately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [TestCase.TestCaseId Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.test.webapi.testcase.testcaseid?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false, IsRequired=false)]
public int TestCaseId { get; set; }
```